# Ambiguous schema in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Schema:

```
|-- c0: string (nullable = true)
|-- c1: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- c2: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |-- orangeID: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- orangeId: string (nullable = true)
```

I am trying to flatten the schema above in spark.

Code:

```
var df = data.select($"c0",$"c1.*").select($"c0",explode($"c2")).select($"c0",$"col.orangeID", $"col.orangeId")
```

The flattening code is working fine. The problem is in the last part where the 2 columns differ only by 1 letter (orangeID and orangeId). Hence I am getting this error:

Error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Ambiguous reference to fields StructField(orangeID,StringType,true), StructField(orangeId,StringType,true);
```

Any suggestions to avoid this ambiguity will be great.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

turn on the spark sql case sensitivity configuration and try

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=true")
```

Comment: In pyspark 2.3, this doesn't seem to work with this syntax.  Instead:  conf.set("spark.sql.caseSensitive", "true") on your SparkConf instance

Comment: The parameter and it’s value will be same. You are running from eclipse or ide then you need to have any configuration using sparkconf