# In pyspark 2.3, how can I deal with ambiguous column names caused by case insensitivity after json schema inference?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Pyspark 2.3, assume I have a JSON document that looks like this:

```
{
   "key1": {
       "key2": "abc",
       "KEY2": "def"
    }
}
```

In actuality, I have billions of these documents and each document has, potentially, hundreds (or even thousands) of deeply nested structures which periodically change.  But this simple document illustrates the problem.

If I do:

```
df = session.read.json(<file>)
df.select('key1.key2')
df.select('key1.KEY2')
```

both selects will fail with an error like this:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Ambiguous reference to fields StructField(key2,StringType,true), StructField(KEY2,StringType,true);'
```

It's not practical to hard code the schema via StructType structures because of the breadth of the schema and its changing nature.

How can I deal with this scenario?  Ideally, I would have a way to rename the duplicate columns so they don't conflict (e.g. 'key2_0', 'KEY2_1', etc).  Unfortunately, I can't find any way to either iterate the list of columns or to change the column name without first being able to unambiguously reference the column by name.

Comment: Not a direct duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086415/ambiguous-schema-in-spark-scala.  That deals with scala.  This deals with pyspark.  Someone experienced in both can do the translation, but this answer doesn't directly answer the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set `spark.sql.caseSensitive` to `true` in your `SparkConf` object

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test App")
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.caseSensitive", "true")
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried below

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=true")
```